# Is there a way (or app) to view a Contacts events in calendar view/mode?

Tags: appexchange, contact, calendar

I would like to see all events scheduled for a specific CONTACT (not user) in a calendar view (with the option of list view as well). Is this possible or is there an app available that gives this ability?

Answer (score 0):

There is one app worth checking Calendar Anything

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Hn2kEAC

Since the use case is very specific ,I guess this will be some effort to custom build this one .

There is small project i did which was a generalized component to map for any object and any field to calendar view

https://github.com/msrivastav13/Bootstrap_Resposive_Calendar

You may use the entire front end for your thing and may be change backend code as per your need .